# A (linear) optimization problem subject to (linear) matrix inequality constraints

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, semidefinite-programming

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a Hurwitz matrix, i.e. $A$ satisfies $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda_i< 0$, where $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$. Suppose that the trace of $A$ is normalized to $-1$, that is $\mbox{trace}(A)=-1$. Further, let $\ge$ denote the standard partial order in the set of positive semidefinite matrices.

> **Conjecture.** 
>   $$
> \min_{\substack{X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\ X\ge 0\\ AX+XA^\top \le 0 \\ X-\frac{1}{2} I\le 0}}  \mathrm{trace}(AX)=-\frac{1}{2}.
> $$

I numerically verified the above conjecture for $n=2, 3,\dots,10$ in Matlab using the built-in [LMI optimization solver](https://it.mathworks.com/help/robust/ref/mincx.html). Any hint/comment towards the (dis)proof of this conjecture is very appreciated.

---

**The optimal $X$ is not full rank, in general.**
Consider the following $2\times 2$ matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & \frac{\sqrt{3}+2}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}-2}{2} & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Matrix $A$ has two eigenvalues at $-0.5$.

Let us select
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}-2}{2(\sqrt{3}+2)} \end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to see that both constraints are satisfied and $\mathrm{tr}(AX)=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Observe also that, since $A+A^\top$ possesses a positive eigenvalue, $X=\frac{1}{2}I$ violates the constraint $AX+XA^\top\le 0$ and it is not an admissible solution.

Comment: You dont need the first constraint. Write $A=SDS^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal and define $Y=S^{-1}XS$. Then $trace(AX)=trace(SDYS^{-1})=trace(DY)$ and $Y<=1/2I$ from which $trace(DY)\geq -1/2 trace(D)=-1/2$ follows.

Comment: @user35593: I think I'm missing something. Since $S$ is in general not orthogonal, $Y$ is typically non-symmetric. Hence, what does $Y\le \frac{1}{2} I$ mean for a non-symmetric matrix $Y$?

Comment: I missed that X is symmetric and thought that <= means all eigenvalues are smaller than. Not sure yet if my "prove" can be fixed.

Comment: Are you sure that $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & \frac{\sqrt{3}+2}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}-2}{2} & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: @Mahdi: Yes, you are right: the matrix is not diagonalizable. Thanks for spotting this! However, my conjecture seems to be true (numerically) for every Hurwitz stable matrix (i.e. diagonalizability is not required). I edited the OP accordingly.

Comment: What is the minimizing $X$ for $$A =\left[\begin{matrix}-0.5&-0.2&1\cr0&-0.5&1\cr1.01&-1&0\end{matrix}\right]$$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $trace(AX)=-1/2$ for $X=(1/2) I$. Assume $A$ diagonal. Note $A + A^T \le 0$, so $AX+X A^T \le 0$. If $A$ diagonal, then this $X$ is obviously optimizes the minimum, as $X\le (1/2) I$ is your constraint.

If $A'$ is not is diagonal, write $A'=U A U^*$, $trace(UAU^* UXU^*)=trace(AX)$.
And $UXU^*\le U(1/2)IU^*=(1/2)I$. And $UAXU^* + UXA^*U^* \le 0 \Leftrightarrow AX +X A^* \le 0$, so constraints are invariant under transformation $U$. Take optimum $U X U^*$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I think I'm missing something. Are you claiming that the optimal $X$ is always of the form $X=\frac{1}{2}I$?

Comment: yes. strangly you could even always take exactly this $X$.

Comment: Then I don't think your claim is true. See the edit in my OP.

Comment: Indeed, then optimum is $U X U^*$ as explained in my answer. $X=1/2$ for $A$ diagonal.

Comment: Ok, so your claim is that the solution is invariant under unitary similarity transformations. I agree. Further, I would say that the optimum is $X=\frac{1}{2}I$ in the case $A+A^\top\le 0$ (not just $A$ diagonal). Otherwise, the explicit form of the optimum $X$ seems tricky (cf. the explicit example in my edited OP).

Comment: my proof is correct, so always $X=1/2$ is the solution. search the flaw in your comment.

Comment: Your proof is correct when $A+A^\top\le 0$. However when $A+A^\top\not\le 0$, taking $X=\frac{1}{2}I$ violates the constraint $AX+XA^\top\le 0$ and so it does not represent an admissible solution.

Comment: but $U(A+A^*)U^* = UAU^*+(UAU^*)^*=UAU^* + UA^* U^* \le 0$

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable and has strictly negative eigenvalues, then it is not true in general that $A+A^\top \le 0$. Take for instance $A=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2} & 2\\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$, $A+A^\top$ has eigenvalues $\{-3,+1\}$.

Comment: This answer assumes that $A$ is symmetric. But this is not assumed in the original question. For $A$ symmetric the answer is correct, but this is not the interesting case.

Answer (score 0):

Up to a unitary matrix $U$, $X$ is diagonal with all eigenvalues between $0$ and $1/2$ the other constraint on $AX$ implies that the diagonal entries  of $U^*AUU^*XU$ are $\le 0$ and so are those of $U^*AU$.  Take $\text{tr}(AX)$ summing the diagonal terms we see that as convex combination the minimum  could be atteigned as $\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(A)$.

The $X$ is the diagonal with entries equal $1/2$ except the terms $x_{i,i}$ where $x_{i,i}=0$ if $ a'_{i,i}=0$ (entry of $U^*AU$)  is possible but in general there (is) should be a counter example to your conjecture.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see your point, however I couldn't find any numerical counterexample yet (I've run an extensive number of random numerical simulation for $n=2,3,\dots,10$). If you have some ideas about how to construct such a counterexample, please let me know.

Comment: Pick $A$ with strictly negative diagonal and $A+A^T$ having some positive eigenvalue, just that.

Comment: Or it is more complicated

Comment: Yes, I think it is more complicated than that. However, if you manage to find an explicit counterexample, please let me know.

Comment: Try to find $A+A^T$ a $2\times 2$ matrix having one positive eignevalue at least and such that $U^*AU$ has strictly negative diagonal for all unitary $U$, the counter example is equivalent to that.

Comment: $U^*=U^T$ real matrice

Comment: In the $2\times 2$ case I don't think it is possible to find such a matrix $A$. Indeed, in case $A+A^\top\not<0$, by virtue of the Schur-Horn Theorem, there always exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that $U^\top A U$ has one diagonal entry equal to $\mathrm{tr}(A)$ and the other entry equal to zero.

Comment: ok then so if we take $A$ in this form can a diagonal $X$ do the constraint $AX+XA^T$ it got to have a $1/2$ term on its diagonal we are in dimension $2$.

Comment: Any luck using the explicit solution for a Lyapunov Equation? For $AX+XA^\top=-Q$, $Q\succeq 0$, the unique solution is $X = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{A^\top t}Qe^{At}dt$. If one chooses $Q=\mbox{diag}(-\mbox{real}(\lambda_i))$, $tr(AX)=-tr(Q)/2=-1/2$. But then I am only able to show $X\leq \beta^2 ||F||||F^{-1}|| I$, where $A=FJF^{-1}$ and $\beta$ is such that $||e^{Jt}||\leq \beta e^{\sigma t}$.